# How can I delete stack view from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistoryboard, uistackview

I'm trying to make my UI design by stack view. Unfortunately, I'm unable, so now I want to delete stackview from my storyboard. I have no idea how to delete it and go restore my previous design without stackview. So how do I do this ?

I already tried this:

```
Select the stackview and  click Editor -> Unembed
```

But this situation deleted stack view and the design didn't change back to before stackview[image]

Thank you

Comment: Editor -> Unembed should be enough, have you tried to restart xcode?

Comment: @RashwanL how can i restart Xcode?. i did not find any option to restart

Comment: Just close the application and start it again.

Comment: @RashwanL design not change like before stackview

Comment: Could you upload your project and send the link someway and I´ll try to help you from there.

Comment: @RashwanL thanks i was delete that and recreate . whatever can you share any link ? easiest way  to learn stackview for UI design .

Comment: Check my answer with two tutorials and also my comment about deleting the stackview.

Answer (score 13):

Editor -> Unembed should be enough to delete the StackView. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tut%E2%80%A6) and [here](https://www.appcoda.com/stack-views-intro/) are two tutorials about StackViews that you can learn how it works and how to properly implement it.

Answer (score 8):

In order to delete a Stack View, two methods:

(A) (1) open the navigator then the outline view; (2) select the Stack View that we want to delete/remove (see [select the Stack View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCEdk.png)); (3) In the top Xcode tool banner click Editor then Unembed.(see [Editor-->Unembed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWIXZ.png) ) The above will remove the Stack View, which was selected 
(A) method removes the Stack that "embeds" the UI elements.  The UI elements are kept.

(B) (1) open the navigator then the outline view; (2) select the Stack View that we want to delete/remove; (3) hit the "delete" key
(B) method removes the Stack and the "embedded" UI elements.  The UI elements are deleted as well.